# State becomes empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Counter File

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Widget from "./widget";

const Counter = () => {
const [form, setForm] = useState(<></>)
const [text, setText] = useState("")

const onCounterChange =() => {
    setText(text)
}
const formLoad =() =>{
    setForm(
        <Widget 
    onCounterChange={onCounterChange}
    children={
        
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) =>{
            setText(e.target.value)
        }}/>
        
    }
    />
    )
}
return (
    <div>
        {text}
    <button onClick={formLoad}>
        load widget
    </button>
    {form}
    </div>
)
}

export default Counter
```

Widget File

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Widget(props) {
  return (
    <div className="buttons">
        {props.children}
        <button onClick={props.onCounterChange}>Save</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have created small text printing page . for some purpose I have added children in a diff component and handling widget in a state , so when I try to change the data , text state is changing but when I click save text state becomes empty

Comment: Why are you putting a component in state? State should really only store data structures (strings, booleans, arrays, objects etc), so its a bit of an antipattern. Your component should be referenced in the JSX and the state should inform that JSX how it's to be rendered.

Comment: Like @Andy mentioned, this is a rather strange structure. I'm assuming this **might** work if you assign `text` as the `value` attribute of the input, but even if that does work, you might face other issues with this structure.

Comment: @Andy Thanks andy yeah after I removed the widget from state and its working fine

Comment: @ArunLazer no problem. I added an answer anyway which maybe closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment putting a component in state probably isn't the best way of approaching this. Instead I would have a boolean state that allows you to toggle the component on/off.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ showWidget, setShowWidget ] = useState(false);
  const [ text, setText ] = useState('');

  function handleChange(e) {
    setText(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleClick() {
    setShowWidget(!showWidget);
  }
  
  function handleSave() {
    console.log(`Saved state: ${text}`);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      
      <p className="text">Current state: {text}</p>
      
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        Load widget
      </button>
      
      {showWidget && (
        <Widget>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <button onClick={handleSave}>Save</button>
        </Widget>
      )}
    
    </div>
  );
}

function Widget({ children }) {
  return <div className="widget">{children}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.widget { margin-top: 1em; }
.text { margin-bottom: 1em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I don't know do u know who does it and Andy can u state why the state becoming empty when we click save btn

Comment: It doesn't become empty. You can check that by clicking the button again. The handler will log whatever value is currently in state. @ArunLazer

Comment: yes I checked it becomes the initial value actually